# Consumer not be able to poll message from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I started two consumers to consume messages from Kafka, there were six partitions, so each consumer was assigned three partitions. I found the consumers could not poll any messages after consuming a while, I could see the lag was there, that means there were still unpolled messages.

When I killed the program and restarted it, the consumers could consume the remaining messages, but after a while, it stopped again although there were remaining messages.

There were no any error messages, part of my code as following please:

```
 KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consum = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]>(props);
 ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = kconsumer.poll(timeoutInMS);
```

I started two threads in one JVM, each thread will create itself KafkaConsumer.

I used AsyncCommit,and I set the callback class is null. such as:

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = ...;
consumer.commitAsync(offsets, null);
```

Did this caused the issue please?

Comment: The question as it stands does not provide enough information for anybody to give a helpful answer, can you please provide additional details? Are there any errors in the logs, the code that you are using to consume, ...

Comment: Looking at threaddumps might provide some insights

Comment: how to see that please, do you mean see Kafka broker's thread dumps?

Comment: Are you polling the records in a some kind of loop? Or is the provided code the only poll call?

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see more code, so it is hard to know what properties you do have, but `KafkaConsumer` is not thread-safe; it would be wiser to start multiple instances of your application, rather than two threads in the same JVM.

In any case, you can find copyable examples of Java Consumers on Confluent's site, either sync commits or async.

Here is [the more-advanced basic example](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#basic-poll-loop) than a simple `while(true) { poll(); }` that allows you to extend and wrap a Thread or ExecutorService around.

```
public abstract class BasicConsumeLoop<K, V> implements Runnable {
  private final KafkaConsumer<K, V> consumer;
  private final List<String> topics;
  private final AtomicBoolean shutdown;
  private final CountDownLatch shutdownLatch;

  public BasicConsumeLoop(Properties config, List<String> topics) {
    this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
    this.topics = topics;
    this.shutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    this.shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  }

  public abstract void process(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record);

  public void run() {
    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);

      while (!shutdown.get()) {
        ConsumerRecords<K, V> records = consumer.poll(500);
        records.forEach(record -> process(record));
        // commit();
      }
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
      shutdownLatch.countDown();
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
    shutdown.set(true);
    shutdownLatch.await();
  }
}
```